# How can I use an 'or' statement to define conditions for selection from a postgresql table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm new to SQL and I want to select all entries from a table when, say, one or more of its columns are empty ie.

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE column1 IS NULL (or) column2 IS NULL;
```

Can anyone tell me the syntax of this?

Comment: SQL actually has an `OR` keyword. Your example is completely correct -- just change `(or)` to `OR`, and you'll be golden. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've pretty much got it already:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE column1 IS NULL OR column2 IS NULL;
```

You can chain Boolean operators (AND, OR, NOT) in SQL statements, using parentheses to make precedence explicit where necessary:

```
SELECT * 
FROM my_table 
WHERE (NOT (column1 IS NULL OR column2 IS NULL) 
  AND (column3 IS NOT NULL OR column4 = "some_value");
```

Do note, though, that despite how it may appear, `IS NOT NULL` is effectively a single keyword; something like `column NOT IS NULL` will provoke a syntax error.